# display arithmetic operations using onclick event in typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript

This is my first attempt on learning ionic framework. i have started a project in which i want to take two numbers as input and display the specific operation like sum, square, division through buttons using onclick event.
**.html**

```
<ion-content padding>
<div ng-app="">

    <p>First Number: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="p"/> </p>

    <p>Second Number: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="q" /> </p>

</div>
    <div>
    <button t (click)='onAdd();'>Sum</button>
    <button t (click)='onMul();'>Product</button>
    <button t (click)='onSquare();'>Square</button>
    <button t (click)='onDivide();'>Division</button>
</div>
</ion-content>
```

**.ts**

```
    export class HomePage {

p:number =0;

q:number =0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
```

}

```
onAdd(p:number,q:number){

console.log("sum={{ p + q }}")
```

}

```
 onMul(p:number,q:number){

console.log("mul={{ p * q }}");
```

}

```
onSquare(p:number,q:number){

console.log("square={{ p * p }},{{ q * q }}");
```

}

```
 onDivide(p:number,q:number){

console.log("divide={{ p / q }}");
```

}

```
}
```

It do not show me output on clicking buttons. I have also imported angular libraries...can u please help ..?

Comment: 1st question did you get any error in console.? 2nd question can you show the screenshot of the console.

Comment: It is not showing any error message .@biswajit-rout

Comment: Please, format code blocks in your question in a proper way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code at html

```
  <p>First Number: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="p"/> </p>
  <p>Second Number: <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="q" /> </p>
  <button (click)='onAdd()'>Sum</button>
  <p>{{ result }}</p>
```

then do this on component.ts

```
  result: number;
  p: number = 0;
  q: number = 0;

  onAdd() {
    this.result = this.p + this.q;
  }
```